# Count number of entries in each column with result in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with many columns. I want to count the number of times something is entered into each column.

```
#Example data
Gender<-c("","Male","Male","","Female","Female")
location<-c("UK","France","USA","","","")
dataset<-data.frame(Gender,location, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

There are 4 entries in the gender column and 3 entries in the location column.

I want the results to be in a dataframe such as:

```
result<-data.frame(Results=c("Gender","location"), Totals=c(4,3))
```

Can anyone suggest an approach to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R option using `stack` + `colSums`

```
setNames(
  rev(stack(colSums(dataset != ""))),
  c("Results", "Total")
)
```

gives

```
   Results Total
1   Gender     4
2 location     3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `names`of `dataset`as one column for `result`and calculate the `Totals` by counting how often `grep` matches anything that is a character (as opposed to nothing in an empty cell):

```
result <- data.frame(
  Results = names(dataset),
  Totals = sapply(dataset, function(x) length(grep(".", x)))
)
rownames(result) <- NULL
```

Result:

```
result
   Results Totals
1   Gender      4
2 location      3
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
ngen <- sum(dataset$Gender != "") #sum number entries in column that are not empty

nloc <- sum(dataset$location != "") #sam thing

Totals <- c(ngen,nloc)


result<-data.frame(Results=c("Gender","location"), Totals)
```

You can simplify some of the steps if you want, but that would be the detailed way.